# Forcing Element Redraw and Prevent Browser Freezing

Tags: javascript

I have some vanilla JavaScript that changes the innerHTML of a div and then runs a computationally heavy loop. Right now it freezes the browser and doesn't show any updated stuff until it finishes everything.

Instead I'd like to force a redraw immediately after I change the innerHTML and breakup the loop into individual steps that doesn't freeze the browser.

I tried putting the loop into a setTimeout with a value of 1, but that didn't do anything. It did seem to work (in Chrome at least) with a timeout of at least 100ms, but that causes a noticeable delay.

I also tried some other things to force a redraw (like [this](https://martinwolf.org/before-2018/blog/2014/06/force-repaint-of-an-element-with-javascript/) and some of [these](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a)) but it didn't work.

I also tried to split the loop into individual steps but again had issues with the timeout time as well as performing an iterated variable through a timeout function.

```
var stuff = "...";
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = stuff;

for(var i = 0; i < someClass.length; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("something")[i].style.backgroundImage = computationallyHeavyFunction(document.getElementsByClassName("something")[i].getAttribute("data-something"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when manipulating dom it advisable to process them into RAF/or function loop and not `for loop`, since it's a rendering you should wait for each rendering step to finish before moving to the next one without bogging the whole CPU/RAM usage.

with function loop you could do

```
async function run(i = 0){
  if(i < someClass.length){
     document.getElementsByClassName("something")[i].style.backgroundImage = await computationallyHeavyFunction(document.getElementsByClassName("something")[i].getAttribute("data-something"));
     
     // you should check the element is finish before running this part
     i++
     run(i)
  }
}

run()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I implemented the code but it waits until everything is computed before rendering. How would you recommend checking the element is finished before executing each run command?

Comment: you could use promise or async/await on computationallyHeavyFunction to wait it finish, and I edit the code to reflect it.